# Ubuntu 16.04 cursor artefacts

Tags: ubuntu, mouse-cursor

OS:Ubuntu 16.04
PC: Lenovo B-570
All updates installed.
I have a garbage around cursor that interferes to see some text or picture.
Command `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme` helps for a while and in short time the garbage around the cursor returns.
Could someone help to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Can you please attach a screenshot or a visual evidence of that? It would be helpful to identify the problem.

Comment: http://ipev.ru/image/lJv
http://ipev.ru/image/lJz

Comment: The squares are places where the cursor is.

Comment: Add that to an answer if it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a possible solution of this trouble, I have made the total uninstall of all NVidia proprietary drivers and reinstall the new one from the offsite. At the moment the garbage disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly if this helps, but I entered these commands and this garbage disappeared. 
`sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop`
`sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10`